# In expressjs application how to handle array with POST request in API endpoint?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, express, rest

I'm trying to build expressjs API endpoint. For my application purpose object will come to another server and it's multiple object. I need to convert it an array and after that I need to push it to my database or others.

Also I'm using express 4+ so that's why I didn't use body-parser because it's included with express.

###Note: Data comes from another server and it's "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format.

I expect data will be like this static data:

```
    [
        {
            "name": "As Md Habibullah",
            "phone": "+457578424",
            "email": "fhhgssa@yahoo.com",
            "car_brand": "Mercedes-Benz",
            "car_number": "256858"
        },
        {
            "name": "Filippo Masiero",
            "phone": "+hgfhfhfg",
            "email": "ghjhghjhg@yahoo.com",
            "car_brand": "Mercedes-Benz",
            "car_number": "25586458"
        },
        {
            "name": "Azad Ahmed",
            "phone": "+ghjggffg",
            "email": "jghjh@yahoo.com",
            "car_brand": "Mercedes-Benz",
            "car_number": "2566868"
        },
        {
            "name": "Md Musa",
            "phone": "+fgjhfgjfh",
            "email": "dfgyfyhfggh@yahoo.com",
            "car_brand": "Mercedes-Benz",
            "car_number": "256858"
        }
    ]
```

I assume data will comes to my endpoint, it's multiple object and I need to do an array like multiple object: `{}, {}, {}`

I want to do an array like: `[{}, {}, {}, {}]`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the data comes as JSON, but clothed in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, content-type, then you will have to use the express middleware for that content-type.  That will give you decoded JSON as plain text which you will then have to manually parse into a Javascript object like this:

```
// middleware for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-type 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post("/somerouter", (res, res) => {
    try {
        // parse decoded body text from JSON into Javascript object
        let obj = JSON.parse(req.body);
        console.log(obj);
        // process obj here
        res.send("ok");
    } catch(e) {
       console.log("bad JSON", e);
       res.sendStatus(400);
    }
});
```

Ideally, the request would be sent as `application/json` and then you can use the `express.json()` middleware and the JSON will automatically be parsed into your object.

---

But, if your `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data is just form data, then it is already parsed for you and is already in `req.body` as properties on that object.  You just access it directly in `req.body`:

```
// middleware for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-type 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post("/somerouter", (res, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    // process data in req.body and then send some response
    res.send("ok");
});
```

Comment: Thanks,
Actually I am using
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
but I miss here try and catch block.

Comment: It's not working.
---------------------
bad JSON SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @AsMdHabibullah - Well, then the client isn't sending valid JSON in that application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoded body.  We can't really help further unless you show us EXACTLY what the client is sending.  In the code I show, what does `console.log(req.body)` show?

Comment: Well, apparently that's not JSON (which isn't what I thought from your question), it's just regular form data.  If you did `console.log(req.body)` like I asked for, you'd see what you have.  The data will already be in there without even using `JSON.parse()`.  That's what you get.

Comment: {
    first_name: '',
    phone: '',
    MODELLO: '',
    TARGA: '',
    template: 'Gentile {{first_name}}, le ricordiamo che nel mese di maggio è previsto il tagliando annuale della sua {{MODELLO_2}} targata {{TARGA_2}} che potrà effettuare presso la nostra sede previo appuntamento. Può prenotare anche online cliccando sul link https://www.internazionaleauto.com/officina-autorizzata  Cordiali Saluti Internazionaleauto Team'
  }

Comment: Also I got an error ----> Server Response
Error Occurred A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of ok

Comment: I can receive plane text also, Right?

Comment: You can receive lots of different formats, if the client sends them.  But if the client is sending form data, then you use the form data it sends.  Remove the `JSON.parse()`.  That isn't needed.  Your data is already in `req.body`.  That's what your  client is sending.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216030/discussion-between-as-md-habibullah-and-jfriend00).

Comment: I updated my answer to show using the form data as it is being sent.